# How to detect unused resources in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is there a way in Xamarin.Android to detect unused resources? I'd like to specifically detect drawables that I'm no longer using.

I believe that the Resource.designer.cs and the R.java in \obj could be used to create a program that does this I'm just not sure if there is a way already out there? In Android you can normally use Lint to detect this but it appears to detect everything as unused when pointed at a Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Any insights on this?

Comment: I did not get any further myself. I simply deleted what I noticed I wasn't using. I guess people generally aren't worried about resources given the massive size of Xamarin Android apps in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `lint` tool with Xamarin.Android projects, we have a new xbuild/msbuild property `AndroidLintEnabled` with this property set to `true` either by adding it to a command line

> /p:AndroidLintEnabled=true

or by adding it to the .csproj

> <AndroidLintEnabled>true</AndroidLintEnabled >

the android lint tool will be run and the warnings/errors will be output as normal xbuild/msbuild errors and warnings.

Comment: There is any way to pass the parameter in Xamarin studio android project? I'm gettingInvalid element 'AndroidLintEnabled' in project file. when added to the end of csproj.

Comment: @jzeferino where did you add the element? You have add it under one of the `PropertyGroup` element

Comment: I've added it in the end of the .csproj. Can you detail where I can use the /p:AndroidLintEnabled=true in the Xamarin studio build options?

Comment: `/p:AndroidLintEnabled=true` is a MSBuild flag, you can use it when you're building the app from command line

Comment: Yes I know that but I'm not building it from the command line. I'm using xamarin studio. There is any way to pass the flag via build settings under xamarin studio?

Comment: @jzeferino it's not unfortunately

Comment: @jzeferino and as a project property, mentioned in the answer

Comment: I added it under PropertyGroup but no warnings shown in the warnings section in xamarin studio.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not working with Visual Studio for Mac

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know, is human work.

I think that the better, way is exclude all drawable files, compile, check drawable errors, add one by one and the drawables don't be added you will delete.

Yeah, I know is a lot of work, but there any util that helps.

Other way, is search in all your Project every drawable file name. If the only place you get this file is Resources, delete it.

Sorry, don't help you with another solution :(

Comment: Yeah for sure. Just was curious at the time if there was any automated utility.

Comment: you are developer, why don't create any tool? if you need help, please contact me :D

Comment: Modern Problems Requires modern Solutions.